# wxPython Display a random image from an array of images using MVC pattern

Tags: python, model-view-controller, wxpython

I'm trying to learn the MVC pattern while learning wxPython.  I'm trying to display a random image from an array of images and I have no idea where to go from here.  I have left out the array part because I'm not sure if that goes in the model or the controller.  None of the tutorials I've found easily explain what I'm trying to do.  Most important part of this is I want to understand how MVC works using this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# import statements
import wx
import random

# define GUI class
class ViewFrame(wx.Frame): # view

    # default constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Display Random Image', size=(600, 400))

        # create a new panel
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        # create status bar
        statusBar=self.CreateStatusBar()

        # create an event handler object
        self.eventHandler = EventHandler()

        # TODO: create a location for a PNG file from the image[i] array

        # create button
        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Change Image")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.eventHandler.onButton)

    # end __init__

# end ViewFrame class

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# define event handler
class EventHandler(): # controller

    self.action = Action()

    # define a button action method
    def onButton(self, event):

        self.action.change()
    # TODO: figure out how to take the random return value 
    #       and display the image[i] to the view

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Action(): # model

    def __init__(self, images = 5):
        self.images = images
        self.change()

    def change(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1, self.images)
        return self.value

# end Action class

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    app=wx.App()
    frame=ViewFrame(parent=None, id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Model` is really a list of images, the data you are operating on.
The `View` class should not create the controller class, the controller should be injected via Dependency Injection to the view class.

The `event` parameter is from wx framework, if your logic does not need it don't send it to the controller.

When creating the view, the view calls `setView` to the controller, so the controller could call methods of the view.

```
import wx
import random


# define GUI class
class ViewFrame(wx.Frame):  # view

    # default constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, id, eventHandler):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Display Random Image', size=(600, 400))

        # create a new panel
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # create status bar
        statusBar = self.CreateStatusBar()

        # create an event handler object
        self.eventHandler = eventHandler
        self.eventHandler.setView(self)

        # TODO: create a location for a PNG file from the image[i] array

        # create button
        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Change Image")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.changeImageClick)

    def changeImageClick(self, event):
        self.eventHandler.changeImageClick()


    def setImage(self, image_path):
        #implement set image 
        pass


class EventHandler:

    # self.action = Action() --> produces a NameError, self does not defined

    def __init__(self, images, view=None):
        self.images = images
        self.view = view

    # define a button action method
    def changeImageClick(self): # button should be lowercase
        random_image = random.choice(self.images)
        self.view.setImage(random_image)

    def setView(self, view):
        self.view = view

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    images = ['image_one.png', 'image_two.png']
    frame = ViewFrame(parent=None, id=1, eventHandler=EventHandler(images))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```